# How do I write the command to give 10^100 in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I am confused as to how write 10^100 in LaTeX, I tried $10^100$ but it's not correct, how do I solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If your exponent (or index) is longer than one character, you have to surround it with braces. So write `$10^{100}$`.

Comment: A good intro to LaTeX can be had [here](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).

Comment: @KersouMan the documented rule is simpler: always surround the argument with braces, `10^{2}` or `10^{1000}`